# Не могу установить модем билаин

Tags: ubuntu, модемы

Ubuntu установил без проблем.

1) Чтобы установить русский язык, нужен инет.

2) Модем установить не получилось, модем видит, но при запуске `*.exe` кукиш показывает.

Вопрос как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: "что бы", "руский", "видет", "запуски", "даной" Аааааааааааа!!!!!

Comment: @ArcherGodson что делать, неправильный русский, наряду с "албанским" и "падонкафским" жаргонами они почему-то считают языком общения в инете

Answer (score 1):

Для начало следовало хоть что-то почитать про ОС в которой собираетесь работать!
Итак:
 1. Русский язык в системе и так есть - посмотри в языковых настройках;   
 2. Запуск exe-шника не требуется, т.к. а) он установит драйвера от винды, которые в убунте не нужны; б) установит ненужное приложение - но сделать этого не сможет и вывалится в ошибку;
 3. "Начиная с версии Ubuntu 9.10 большинство USB-модемов определяются и работают нормально независимо от оператора сотовой связи. - это цитата с help.ubuntu.ru". Посмотри вывод команды lsusb - есть ли там модем? Проверь обнаружило ли устройство приложение NetworkManager (в трее указаны сетевые соединения и устройства) - возможно требуется настройка самого соединения: "стандартный апплет NetworkManager позволит создать «Новое широкополосное соединение», где мастер поможет выбрать регион, оператора и тариф. " .

Answer (score 0):

Я очень много пользовался подобными модемами. И сейчас на убунте прекрасно работает билайновский модем. Однако есть нюанс с производителями. Я как-то попробовал модемы от ZTE, а работали они в линуксе вообще довольно паршиво. Поэтому, когда я брал модем от билайна, я искал модем именно от производителя huawei. Подробнее здесь http://ubuntism.ru/2010/06/3g-usb-modem-ubuntu-lucid/ .